# Pandas dataframe plot time axis format total seconds into elapsed HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas dataframe where index value are integers 0-10000 and each value corresponds to 1 second. I have 1 `temp` column in dataframe. I can create a plot of temp vs time using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

With this time is displayed on x-axis in seconds (index value), I'd like to display time in a more readable way for example 50min 5 sec, instead of 3005 seconds. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> index value are integers 0-10000 and each value corresponds to 1 second

Convert the index [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and specify the `unit` as `seconds`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': np.random.randn(10_001).cumsum()})

df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='seconds')
df.plot(figsize=(10, 3))
```

[image: figure with timedelta axis]